# Minimizing the norm of the difference of two vectors.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, inner-products

Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a a vector space of finite dimension. Let $\mathcal{H_1}$ be a subspace of $\mathcal{H}$. Considering some vector $|\phi\rangle \in \mathcal{H}$ i need to show that there exists only one element of $\mathcal{H_1}$, say $|\phi_1\rangle$, that minimizes the norm $\|\phi - \phi_1\|$.

The norm is, of course,
\begin{align}
\|\phi - \phi_1\| &= \sqrt{\langle\phi-\phi_1|\phi-\phi_1\rangle} \\
&= \sqrt{ \langle\phi|\phi\rangle-\langle\phi|\phi_1\rangle-\langle\phi_1|\phi\rangle-\langle\phi_1|\phi_1\rangle }.
\end{align}

I don't really know to progress any further to show that $\phi_1$ is unique or how to find $\phi_1$.

I seem to be stuck at this point so any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a finite-dimensional inner product space $\mathcal H$ the orthogonal complement of a subspace is indeed a complement:
$$
\mathcal H = \mathcal H_1 \oplus \mathcal H_1^\perp, \quad\text{where}\quad
\mathcal H_1^\perp = \{\, |\psi\rangle \in\mathcal H \mid \langle x | \psi \rangle=0 \text{ for all $x\in\mathcal H_1$} \,\}.
$$
Hence, given $|\phi\rangle\in\mathcal H$ you can always decompose it uniquely as
$$
|\phi\rangle = |\phi_a\rangle+|\phi_b\rangle \quad\text{with $|\phi_a\rangle\in\mathcal H_1$ and $|\phi_b\rangle\in\mathcal H_1^\perp$}.
$$
Now for $|\phi_1\rangle\in \mathcal H_1$ the calculation you started can be continued using $\langle\phi_1|\phi_b\rangle=0$ and $\langle \phi_a|\phi_b\rangle = 0$.
\begin{align}
\|\phi - \phi_1\|^2 &= \langle\phi-\phi_1|\phi-\phi_1\rangle \\
&= \|\phi\|^2 - \langle \phi|\phi_1\rangle - \langle\phi_1|\phi\rangle + \|\phi_1\|^2 \\
&= \underbrace{\|\phi_a\|^2 + \|\phi_b\|^2}_{\|\phi\|^2} - \langle\phi_a|\phi_1\rangle - \langle \phi_1|\phi_a\rangle + \|\phi_1\|^2 \\
&= \|\phi_b\|^2 + \|\phi_a-\phi_1\|^2.
\end{align}
Hence, the minimal value $\|\phi-\phi_1\|^2$ can obtain is $\|\phi_b\|^2$ and this happens exactly when $\phi_1=\phi_a$.

Comment: That was much simpler than i thought it would be. Thank you very much for your answer, it was very helpful!